# Parse String to Generate Output String in Specific Format

Tags: c#, string

I am looking to generate a Sequence Number in this format

```
00000A
00000B
00000B
```

and so on till

```
00000Z
```

and then

```
00001A
00001B
00001C
...
00001Z
...
00010A
```

till

```
99999Z
```

I know that I can generate Max 2.6 million rows using this method but I guess that is enough

so, if I have the a String, lets say 26522C, Now i want the next number as 26522D
or If I have 34287Z, i want 34288A

I can write the Algorithm about it but there will be lots of parsing of the input string characters by characters

I was wondering is there any easier way of doing it

```
String GetNextNumberInSequence(String inputString)
{
   if (inputString.Length == 6)
   {  
     var charArray = inputString.ToCharArray();
     char[] inputChars = { charArray[0], charArray[1], charArray[2],charArray[3],charArray[4],charArray[5] };
     if(Char.IsDigit(charArray[5]))
     {
       //Parse first 5 characters
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can either have a parser and to string combination, or you could maintain the current number (in which case you only need the ToString method). Either way I would separate converting between the number and the string and doing anything else

Comment: If it works and you just want to make it faster, then use a profiler to determine which piece is the slowest and work on that.  Otherwise you're just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private static String GetNextNumberInSequence(String inputString)
    {
        var integerpart = int.Parse(inputString.Substring(0, 5));
        var characterPart = inputString[5];
        if (characterPart == 'Z')
            return string.Format("{0}{1}", (++integerpart).ToString("D5"), "A");

        var nextChar = (char)(characterPart + 1);
        return string.Format("{0}{1}", (integerpart).ToString("D5"), nextChar.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by converting a number to **[Base36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36)**.

Take a look at this sample:

```
private const string CharList = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public static String Base36Encode(long input, char paddingChar, int totalWidth)
{
    char[] clistarr = CharList.ToCharArray();
    var result = new Stack<char>();

    while (input != 0)
    {
        result.Push(clistarr[input % 36]);
        input /= 36;
    }

    return new string(result.ToArray()).PadLeft(totalWidth, paddingChar).ToUpper();
}
```

**and then use it this way:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(Base36Encode(i, '0', 6));
}
```

**which will produce this:**

000000, 000001, 000002, 000003, 000004, 000005, 000006, 000007, 000008, 000009, 00000A, 00000B, 00000C, 00000D, 00000E, 00000F, 00000G, 00000H, 00000I, 00000J, 00000K, 00000L, 00000M, 00000N, 00000O, 00000P, 00000Q, 00000R, 00000S, 00000T, 00000U, 00000V, 00000W, 00000X, 00000Y, 00000Z, 000010, 000011, 000012, 000013, 000014, 000015, 000016, 000017, 000018, 000019, 00001A, 00001B, 00001C, 00001D, 00001E, 00001F, 00001G, 00001H, 00001I, 00001J, 00001K, 00001L, 00001M, 00001N, 00001O, 00001P, 00001Q, 00001R, 00001S, 00001T, 00001U, 00001V, 00001W, 00001X, 00001Y, 00001Z, 000020, 000021, 000022, 000023, 000024, 000025, 000026, 000027, 000028, 000029, 00002A, 00002B, 00002C, 00002D, 00002E, 00002F, 00002G, 00002H, 00002I, 00002J, 00002K, 00002L, 00002M, 00002N, 00002O, 00002P, 00002Q, 00002R, 00002S, 00002T...

**and the positive thing about this approach is that you can convert this back to number by using:**

```
public static Int64 Base36Decode(string input)
{
    var reversed = input.ToLower().Reverse();

    long result = 0;
    int pos = 0;

    foreach (char c in reversed)
    {
        result += CharList.IndexOf(c) * (long)Math.Pow(36, pos);
        pos++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I was doing something very similar with bitwise ANDs, but modulo works much better!  +1

Comment: Oh, one improvement you could use is instead of hard coding in the `36`, you could use `CharList.Length`, so that you could easily convert the algorithm to base 32, or base whever

Comment: Why using lowercase letters in the string array.  You could just use uppercase to start with and dispense with the ToUpper() call.  Especially as it would break indexof....

Comment: @BobVale: in my project I'm originally using lowercase and without the padding. This was quick copy-paste from my project and quick adjustment for the answer purpose. Other than that, I agree with you.